# How does the negative charge on endothelium prevent blood coagulation?

Tags: hematology

I was reading about the *factors that keep the blood inside the body in fluid state* and came across a line in my book which states that, "*Smoothness of the endothelium, its negative charge and its normal health are among the important factors*"

Does the vascular endothelium have negative charge on it, and if it does, how does it prevent coagulation of blood or keep it in fluid state?